# How do I create a new pandas dataframe column with the contents of another, but only if the other column meets multiple conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I have the following lines of code in Python Pandas:

```
df['small_homes'] = 0 #creates new column set to zero
df.loc[(df['bathrooms'] == 1) or # if one bathroom 
       (df['bathrooms'] < 2) & # or if less than two bedrooms
       (df['bedrooms'] == 1), # and if one bedroom
       'small_homes'] = 1 # sets small_homes = 1 if true
df.head()
```

I want to create a new column in a dataframe called "Small_homes" that has only listings that have either 1 bathroom (bathrooms column), OR less than 2 bathrooms and exactly 1 bedroom (bedrooms column). I've tried using OR, but it returns ambiguous.

How do I fix?

Thank you!

Comment: Similar to how you're using `&` instead of `and`, you need to use `|` instead of `or`.

Comment: df.loc[(df['bathrooms'] ==1) | (df['bathrooms']< 2)] should fix your issue